# Ehcache Cache Server + BlockingCache ?

Tags: ehcache

Is it possible to use Ehcache Cache Server and have it be configured with blockingCache ? I cant seem to find how to configure this in the ehcache.xml file... only programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare decorated caches programmatically, but also in configuration, see:
http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/cache-decorators#by-configuration

You'd need to add a net.sf.ehcache.constructs.CacheDecoratorFactory implementation that does what you need. I guess in you're case it could do some pattern matching against the Ehcache instance passed to the net.sf.ehcache.constructs.CacheDecoratorFactory#createDecoratedEhcache and return either null, or the cache instance decorated by the BlockingCache.

Word of caution though, is to make sure that on misses, you *always* put back (even null) into the cache, otherwise the write lock for that key/segment won't be unlocked.

Answer (score 9):

To use BlockingCache as the default decorator for your cache via ehcache.xml, first you should implement your own CacheDecoratorFactory, say it's DefaultCacheDecoratorFactory:

```
public class DefaultCacheDecoratorFactory extends CacheDecoratorFactory {
    @Override
    public Ehcache createDecoratedEhcache(Ehcache cache, Properties properties) {
        return new BlockingCache(cache);
    }

    @Override
    public Ehcache createDefaultDecoratedEhcache(Ehcache cache, Properties properties) {
        return new BlockingCache(cache);
    }
}
```

then configure it as part of your cache definition, like this:

```
<cache name="CACHE_NAME" more values here.../>
    <cacheDecoratorFactory class="whatsoever.DefaultCacheDecoratorFactory"/>
</cache>
```

And using cacheManager.getEhCache() to access the cache other than cacheManager.getCache(), because it only returns null for your decorated cache.