# Ehcache get stucked when the cache is time out and 100 request come in at the same time to get data from Database

Tags: spring, ehcache

We use Ehcache in our system to handle cache. Now we are doing performance testing and we get this problem. The time-interval for cache is 1 min, and when the cache is time our after 1 min and at this time, 100 requests come in at same time, the system is stucked. we check the code found the reason is that, all the requests try to get data from database, because it will take 2 seconds to get data from database. Is anyone know how to config Ehcache, so the requests can be synchronized, just wait the first request gets data from database and all the other request just uses the cache?
Any info will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to post the relevant code and configuration.

Comment: @Jukka I can't post my code for some reason and I don't think this is relevant to the code and configuration, so I describe what I encounter.

Comment: BlockingCache will help.
Please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237843/ehcache-cache-server-blockingcache/23630584#23630584